# Get files used by a binary

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to locate a file used by a binary file during its execution. Using strace helps but its way too convoluted, macroed with grep is good enough, but does there exist an utility which can help me dump only files used by a binary?

Answer (score 2):

you can try using:

`lsof -p PID` of the running process

`lsof -c ssh` would show all files opened by processes starting with the letter

Or try `ltrace` or maybe `fuser`

I've seen `strace` be used with some complex `grep` piping.. but it all depends on what exactly the end goal is.

You can also utilize the `-e` options in `strace` to filter, example is:

`sudo strace -t -e trace=open,close,read,getdents,write,connect,accept whoami >/dev/null`

and grep from there..